# ReactJS: Unable to render image in UI from REST API response

Tags: image, rest, reactjs, blob

I have built a REST API that returns an image and I am successfully getting its response through PostMan agent.
[image: PostMan response]
In my React Code, I have this:

```
return fetch(url, sInit)
  .then((response) => {
    let blb = new Blob([response.body], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
    let fileUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blb);
    window.open(fileUrl);
  })
```

The blob url generated does not have the image. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the built-in [`blob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob) method by `fetch`:

```js
fetch(
  'https://images.unsplash.com/35/SRkdurVYQFSFkMyHVwSu_spinnenweb-9536.jpg?dpr=2&auto=compress,format&fit=crop&w=376&h=251&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop='
)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    let fileUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);

    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = fileUrl;
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(img);
  });
```

Comment: Your answer is of great help, but this does not work in IE 8 through 11.

Comment: Did you include a [`fetch` polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch)? `fetch` is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) by these browsers.

Comment: Please check the documentation, `fetch` is supported in IE10 and above, but `blob()` is not supported in any version of Internet Explorer.